# How to calculate page views in Codeigniter and count by IP address?

Tags: codeigniter

Please explain steps how to calculate page views in codeigniter.

Is there any instruction on how to do this.

by using following method:

$this->input->ip_address();

How to Write $this->input->ip_address();  in Below Controller:

**Controller Page**

```
class About extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('array');
        $this->load->model('about_model');
        }

          public function index() {
            $data = array(
            'page_title' => 'About',
            'page_name' => 'site/aboutus/about',
            'about' => $this->about_model->list_all(),
            );
             $this->load->view('site/template', $data);
            }
}
?>
```

Model Page:

```
class About_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function list_all() {
        return $this->db->get('about')->result_array();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

1. `$this->input->ip_address()` to take the user's ip address in the controller
2. In the database you save the ip, the time the user first visited the site and a counter
3. Get the counter: `$this->db->select_sum("counter")->get("views_table");` and process the result.

Comment: i am create new controller and new model?

Comment: its on you. you can do it in any controller and model.

Comment: how to write  $this->input->ip_address()  in controller?

Comment: just echo $this->input->ip_address() you will get the ip then insert it in database.

Comment: <?php 

class About extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('array');
        $this->load->model('about_model');
  }
  
    public function index() {
   $data = array(
            'page_title' => 'About',
            'page_name' => 'site/aboutus/about',
   );
    $this->load->view('site/template', $data);
   }
}
?>

Comment: Owais Arain How to write $this->input->ip_address()

Comment: If you want to do it in index function paste this $ip = $this->input->ip_address() before data array and then insert $ip in db. are you getting my point ?

Comment: $this->input->ip_address() use in model? below comment

Comment: public function insert($ip) {
        $data = array('ip' => $this->input->ip_address());
        $this->db->insert('visitors', $data);
    }